# What is the source of the claim, that Vedas are 1,960,000,000 years old?

Tags: vedas, history, reference-request

Some comments under [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/iBHrdW2-VQQ) claim that Vedas are 1,960,000,000 year old. E.g.,

> neha rajput
>
> 1 year ago
>
> Veda 1 Arab 96 carore 8 lakh 53 hajar old h.is se bi jayda abi time period aur bi bacha h.

What is the source of this claim? Is it found in Vedas or Upanishads?

Comment: Why down votes to my question

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes but Vedas etc don't make such claims.. Also the task of assigning dates to Hindu scriptures are not done by traditional Hindus but by Indologists. Indologists believe that since every book they see around them has an author and was written at some point of time the same must be true for Hindu scriptures. They reject the divine, the super natural aspects which are the basis of religion. They are basically like "outsiders"  who forcefully and completely unwantedly provide their opinions on when do they think the scriptures were written.

Comment: "Most hindus claim that vedas are 1960000000 year old" -- Where did you read this?

Comment: @Rickross is correct. Where did you read such a claim? Moreover its probable that Vedas were written approx 6000 years ago based on various evidences

Comment: @Rickross https://youtu.be/iBHrdW2-VQQ see this from 4:20(time) also read the comments

Comment: @Rickross most hindus believe that vedas are from the start of the universe so it is obvious that vedas are 1960000000 year old.

Comment: " most hindus believe that vedas are from the start of the universe so it is obvious that vedas are 1960000000 year old" -- then are you looking for statements from Vedas which say that Vedas existed since the beginning of the universe? @DarkKnight

Comment: @Rickross yes and also from other scriptures.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about youtube videos are not valid sources for questions. Questions should be directed to the authors of the youtube videos.

Answer (score 1):

Vedas are Anadi, Ananta and Apaurusheya - eternal, infinite and uncreated.

That means they exist forever - before, after and during - Srushti, Sthithi and Pralaya.

The entire modern/scientific thought is entrenched in the notion of everything having a beginning and an end.
Unless you grasp the concept of infinite eternity, you can't fully understand Atma or Paramatma or most Sanatan Dharma spiritual viewpoints.

That being said, if you want to calculate the age of 'current' cycle of creation, and choose that as 'starting date' of Vedas, you can look at either when the current Kalpa began, or when current Brahma's lifespan began.

There are several answers on this site that explain Yuga timeline. I can post later.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,

Comment: Can you give some verses from vedas and upanishades